# Describe vectors v = [x , y] that are orthogonal to u = [a , b].

Tags: vectors

The correct answer is: $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}= a⋅x+b⋅y = 0\rightarrow y = −(a/b)x\rightarrow \mathbf{v}=(t,-\frac{a}{b}t)$. But how did they find $-(a/b)$ and why did they substitute $y$ with $-(a/b)x$?

Comment: What is $[x,y]$? A Lie algebra bracket?

Comment: They solved the equation $ax+by=0$ for $y$ in terms of $x$. It's basic algebra.

Comment: @CélioAugusto, could you illustrate your steps that you take to solve y in terms of x? Thank you in advance!

Comment: take $ax+by=0$ and move $ax$ to the right, so that it became $by=-ax$ and then you divide by $b$. The only problem is that if $b=0$, then the solution won't do (as you cannot divide by $0$), but if $x=b$ and $y=-a$ you get $ab-ab=0$, so the vector $(b,-a)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)$, so any vector $v$ that is a multiple of $(b,-a)$ (that is $v=(bt,-at)$, for some $t$, is orthogonal to $(a,b)$

Comment: @Alessandro You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$ax+by=0  \Longrightarrow ax+by-ax=-ax \Longrightarrow by=-ax \Longrightarrow\frac{by}{b}=-\frac{a}{b}x\Longrightarrow y=-\frac{a}{b}x$$

I am assuming that $b\neq 0$.